# Cloning a specific branch from GitHub - fatal error

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, git-clone

I am trying to clone [this](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/tree/python3) branch from GitHub. I use Ubuntu VM and typed in the terminal:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch python3 git@github.com:HaseloffLab/CellModeller.git
```

Output:

```
Cloning into 'CellModeller'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.118.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried `git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>` and permission is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GitHub help [page](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-ssh-urls),

> **Cloning with SSH URLs**
>
> SSH URLs provide access to a Git repository via
>   SSH, a secure protocol. **To use these URLs, you must generate an SSH
>   keypair on your computer and add the public key to your GitHub
>   account. For more information, see "[Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)"**
>
> When you git clone, git fetch, git pull, or git push to a remote
>   repository using SSH URLs, you'll be prompted for a password and must
>   provide your SSH key passphrase. For more information, see "Working
>   with SSH key passphrases."

You can also use **HTTPS URL** to clone.

In your case it would be :

```
git clone -b python3 https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller.git
```

Read more about **Cloning with HTTPS URL** [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended).